Second order differential equation with non constant coefficient
Is it possible to solve the differential equation for $y(t)$ the following ODE?
$$
y^{\prime \prime}(t)+ \frac{f^{\prime}(t)}{2 f(t)} y^{\prime}(t) + k^{2} y(t) = 0 
$$
It can also be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(t)}} \frac{d (\sqrt{f(t)} y^{\prime}(t))}{dt} + k^{2} y(t) = 0 
$$
I tried some substituition $y(t) = e^{z(t)}$ or $e^{t z(t)}$ but I just end up with another non trivial diferential equation in $z(t)$. I am trying to find a solution that reduces to $A e^{ik t}+ B e^{-i k t}$ when $f(t)$ is independent of $t$.

If $f(t) = t^a$, then we get solution with Bessel functions... $$C_1t^{(1-a)/2} J_{(1-a)/2}(kt)+C_2t^{(1-a)/2} Y_{(1-a)/2}(kt)$$

The logarithmic derivative $f'(t)/f(t)$ suggests to consider $f(t)=\exp(a_0+a_1 t+a_2 t^2+a_3 t^3)$, which is solved by the tri-confluent Heun function(HeunT[] in Mathematica). Simpler cases (some $a_k=0$) give Hermite polynomials, Bessel functions (see comment by @GeraldEdgar), or simple exponentials.

@trying Please check your 2nd equation, I think it should read $f(t)$ instead of $\sqrt{f(t)}$. Else, there is a factor $1/2$ missing in the first equation.

@FredHucht sorry yes, I fixed the typo.

@trying Ok, my comment remains correct.

@GeraldEdgar thanks i understand now.

@FredHucht Do you have any reference for this? Your explanation is a bit vague for me.

My comment as an answer: The ODE can be simplified with the substitution $f(t)\mapsto e^{2G(t)}$ and $G'(t)=g(t)$ to read
\begin{align}
\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
y''(t) + g(t) y'(t) + k^2 y(t) = 0 \,.
\end{align}
It can be seen as an harmonic oscillator with time-dependent friction term $g(t)$.
The case $g(t)\equiv 0$ gives the simplest case
\begin{align}
\label{eq:2}\tag{2}
y(t)=A e^{ik t}+ B e^{-i k t},
\end{align}
while several other choices of $g(t)$ can be integrated using Mathematica, including
\begin{align}
g(t) &= a        && \text{exponentials}                 \label{eq:3a}\tag{3a}\\
g(t) &= a t      && \text{Hermite polynomials}          \label{eq:3b}\tag{3b}\\
g(t) &= a t^2    && \text{tri-confluent Heun functions} \label{eq:3c}\tag{3c}\\
g(t) &= a e^t    && \text{Laguerre polynomials}         \label{eq:3d}\tag{3d}\\
g(t) &= a t^{-1} && \text{Bessel functions }J,Y         \label{eq:3e}\tag{3e}\\
&\ldots
\end{align}
All these cases reduce to \eqref{eq:2} for $a\to0$.
